# Need a tool bar on mobile device key board for web based mobile app

Tags: javascript, ios, css

I am creating a rich text editor app (like evernote) usinh HTML5 technology. I have an rich text editor where user can write or modify text. I am creating this for mobile devices like ipad/iphone/android . When the user focus on the text area the device soft key board comes up moving the view upward. I need a tool bar for editing text (bold, italics, bullet etc) in this app and this should be placed just on top of key board. Can anybody suggest a way in Javascript or css for such scenario.

Regards,
Nil